# Error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

Tags: java, macos, electron

I want to run electron app using chromedriver(java), facing this issue

```
{ [Error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.] code: -1022, domain: 'NSURLErrorDomain' }
```

and can not interact with elements inside application.

MacOS Mojave 10.14.5
ChromeDriver 2.46

Already tried change *info.plist*

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>1.0</string>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>127.0.0.1</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>1.0</string>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: What do you want to load?

Comment: Whenever I'm performing arbitrary requests to localhost I specify it as `http://localhost` or in particular even `http://localhost:8080`. Could you try that? Maybe the protocol is relevant.

Comment: Electron version 3.5.2

Comment: @TienDuong i want to run my electron app and create automated tests for it. So in the code i am using chromedriver. Application was open, but i can not continue. Because of this issue

Comment: @Muli . didn´t help

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for it to fail could be a syntax issue. When I'm taking a look at iOS apps, the XML Syntax goes like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <string>http://localhost</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

rather than the hostname as a key. Try updating it to that structure and also specify a protocol (http).

Comment: Just corrected the code in the  question. Actual  code has the same syntax like you shared

Comment: and after changing keys inside from false to true, has the same result

Comment: No it hasn't. It's still not a dict of a enumerating key and a string value.

Comment: @Arween did that help you? If yes, could you please accept the answer and if not, could you please let me know how I could help you?